# Is it possible to find which vim/tmux has my file open?

Tags: process, vim, tmux, open-files

I use `tmux` at work as my IDE. I also run `vim` in a variety of tmux panes and will fairly often background the process (or alternatively I just close the window - I have vim configured not to remove open buffers when the window is closed). Now I've a problem, because a file that I want to edit is open in one of my other vim sessions but I don't know which one.

Is it possible to find out which one, without manually going through all my windows and panes? In my particular case, I know that I didn't edit it with `vim ~/myfile.txt` because `ps aux | grep myfile.txt` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't tell me *everything*, but I used `fuser ~/.myfile.txt.swp` which gave me the PID of the vim session. Running `ps aux | grep <PID>` I was able to find out which vim session I was using, which gave me a hint as to which window I had it open in.

Thanks to Giles's inspiration and a bit of persistence and luck, I came up with the following command:

```
⚘ (FNAME="/tmp/.fnord.txt.swp"; tmux switch -t $(tmux list-panes -a -F '#{session_name}:#{window_index}.#{pane_index} #{pane_tty}' | grep $(ps -o tty= -p $(lsof -t $FNAME))$ | awk '{ print $1 }'))
```

To explain what this does:

```
(FNAME="/tmp/.fnord.txt.swp";
```

This creates a subshell and sets `FNAME` as an environment variable. It's not, strictly speaking, necessary - you could just replace `$FNAME` with the filename yourself, but it does make editing things easier. Now, working from the inside out:

```
lsof -t $FNAME
```

This produces *only* the PID of the process that has open the file.

```
ps -o tty= -p $(...)
```

This produces the `pts` of the PID that we found using `lsof`.

```
tmux list-panes -a -F '#{session_name}:#{window_index}.#{pane_index} #{pane_tty}'
```

This produces a pane list of entries like `session:0.1 /dev/pts/1`. The first part is the format that tmux likes for targets, and the second part is the `pts`

```
| grep $(...)$
```

This filters our pane list - the trailing `$` is so it will only match the *one* we care about. I discovered that quite by accident as I had `pts/2` and `pts/22`, so there were *two* matches, whoops!

```
| awk '{ print $1 }'
```

This produces the `session:0.1` part of the pane output, which is suitable for passing to `tmux switch -t`.

This should work across sessions as well as panes, bringing to focus the pane that contains your swap file.

Comment: Don't grep for the PID! `ps -p "$pid"` lists that specific PID. And while you're at it, the useful information there is probably the terminal name: `ps -o tty= -p "$pid"`. That identifies the tmux window where this instance of vim is running. I don't know how to do the next step of focusing a window based on the terminal name, maybe something with `switch-client`.

Answer (score 0):

the outline answer to your question is:

```
for all the tmux sessions:
  for all the windows in the session:
      for all the panes in windows:
         for all sub process pids (recursively):
            find the open files
```

all sessions:
tmux list-sessions -F '#{session_id}:#{session_name}

all windows:
tmux list-windows -F '#{window_id}XX#{window_index}XX#{window_name}' -t "$session_id"

all panes:
tmux list-panes -F '#{pane_id}:#{pane_index}:#{pane_pid}' -t ""$session_id":"$window_index""

all sub processe pids:
ps -o pid --no-headers --ppid $pid

open files:
lsof -p $pid

An implementation of the above which displays a tree of:

```
sessions
   windows
      panes
         process
            open files
```

to show which process has a file open (vim in my case too).

[image]

can be found at https://github.com/nkh/tmux-ls

it's been on github for 5 year but I encourage you to clone it in case it is removed (or github crashes)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @TobySpeight Normally I would agree, but the script posted by the author in GitHub is rather lengthy and would not really fit the format of an SE answer, so in this case I think referencing the external resource is reasonable.

Comment: A good answer would describe enough that it remains an answer even when the link itself isn't accessible.  I think at least the principles used should be present for this not to be "[your answer is in another castle](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370)."