# Why is tmux using my drive?

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to unmount a harddisk and have several tmux sessions open.

```
$ sudo umount /mnt/PIHDD
umount: /mnt/PIHDD: target is busy
        (In some cases useful info about processes that
         use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)


$ lsof /mnt/PIHDD/
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
tmux    1415   pi   36r   DIR    8,1    20480    5 /mnt/PIHDD

$ ps 1415
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 1415 ?        Ss    17:26 tmux
```

How can I tell which tmux session to look in, or whatever else the reason is? I assumed some session contains a window where the current directory is on that drive.

I manually looked through all the panes in all the sessions but could not find the offender.

https://superuser.com/a/212913/291007 seems helpful, but `cat /proc/1415/environ`
 does not contain `^TMUX=` at all. It does however contain `^@_=/usr/bin/tmux^@`.
[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/594765/291007) does generate the expected output but does not contain the PID 1415.

According to `lsof -p 1415`, that process has currently open every directory that I have open in tmux - not just those of one session. That means the thread with PID `1415` is actually tmux itself. It's worth noting though that `lsof` only lists the mount point dir `/mnt/PIHDD`, not any file within it.

Something interesting is that `ls /proc/1415/fd` shows the relevant mount point in a different color than the other drives:
[image]

Also perhaps of relevance: The drive mounted to `/mnt/PIHDD` is NTFS-formatted. The drive at `/mnt/oceanPortal` is EXT-4.

**Why is tmux using my hard drive and how do I stop that safely?**

Additional information that could be helpful:

```
$ gdb -p 1415
(gdb) info proc
process 1415
cmdline = 'tmux'
cwd = '/home/pi'
exe = '/usr/bin/tmux'
```

---

I have since I initially asked the question rebooted my raspi, which this was running on, to see whether restarting tmux would re-acquire that file descriptor. Now the `tmux` process, which has a new PID, does no longer have `/mnt/PIHDD` in `/proc/{pid}/fd`.
That means I can not verify any given explanations. On the other hand, if somebody has the same issue and is able to restart tmux, give it a try!

It is possible that [closing the file descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/323180/2550406) would have worked without issues. But I would still like a knowledgeable confirmation for that, and **an explanation why tmux had that fd**.

---

Irrelevant information that may help a future person in my shoes:

- do not [try attaching gdb to tmux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/323180/2550406) from within tmux. If you do, open a new terminal/ssh-connection and do `kill -9` for the pid of gdb which you get from `ps -ax | grep gdb`.

Comment: Related but I didn't get it to work: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309662/66736

Comment: have you tried changing the working dir of the session? `:attach -c /some/dir` . Might be worth checking. From: [A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/274551/127903) of [Q](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268386/how-to-change-default-new-window-directory-from-within-the-tmux)

Comment: @AlexStragies If I understand correctly, this is about the default working dir, right? None of my sessions are currently `cd`'d into that drive and the default working dir is currently `~` which is also not on that drive. (`pwd` gives `/home/pi`)

Comment: Doing `:attach -c /some/dir` in just one session did not help. Would I need to do this in all of them?

Comment: @AlexStragies Please consider also my edited information. I don't know if that is helpful or a red herring though